# How to search entities by multiple arbitrary values?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, entity-framework-5

I have a `customer` entity whose records I want to be able to search by multiple arbitrary attributes.

E.g.:

```
Dictionary<string, string> searchList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
searchList.Add("LastName", "Foo");
searchList.Add("FirstName", "Bar");
```

I could of course write something along these lines:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kv in searchList)
{
    switch (kv.Key)
    {
       case "FirstName" :
          List<Customer> someResultPart = this._dbSet.Where(customer => customer.FirstName == kv.Value).ToList();
       break;
       case "LastName" :
          // etc.
    }
}

// Do intersection of all result parts ...
```

Aside from the fact that querying `n` times and intersecting later on is obviously fugly, I would much rather not have that `switch` statement in there (since it would force me to change it every single time anything in the `Customer` class changes.

Is there any way to:

- "dynamically" build the query based on the `searchList` dictionary, thereby eliminating the need for the `switch` construct?
- "concatenate" the various conditions into a single db query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

```
string predicate = String.Format("{0} = \"{1}\"", kv.Key, kv.Value);
List<Customer> someResultPart = _dbSet.Where(predicate);
```

Or this way:

```
List<Customer> someResultPart = _dbSet.Where("{0}");
```

I'd even constructed full search predicate like this:

```
Dictionary<string, object> searchList = new Dictionary<string, object>();
searchList.Add("LastName", "Foo");
searchList.Add("FirstName", "Bar");
searchList.Add("Id", 42); // yep, not only strings

var conditions = searchList.Select((kvp, i) => String.Format("{0} = @{1}", kvp.Key, i));
string predicate = String.Join(" and ", conditions);
object[] values = searchList.Select(kvp => kvp.Value).ToArray();

var query = _dbSet.Where(predicate, values);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, much appreciated and working like a charm! Is there any easy way to search inside nested (List) properties as well? Along the lines of `searchList.Add("CustomerLikes/CustomerLikedObject.Id", 12345)`?

Comment: @vzwick never tried to use Dynamic LINQ for nested lists, you should verify this functionality by yourself. But it definitely supports nested objects like `Address.Country`

Answer (score 1):

For the second point, you could do:

```
IQueryable<Customer> filtered = this._dbSet;
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kv in searchList)
{
    switch (kv.Key)
    {
       case "FirstName" :
          filtered = filtered
              .Where(customer => customer.FirstName == kv.Value);
          break;
       case "LastName" :
          // etc.
    }
}
List<Customer> resultList = filtered.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Be typesafe!

It is better to construct a list of function that would return the good properties than declare a string variable that will failed if one day you want to alter your column name :

```
    public class Customer { public string FirstName; public string LastName;}
    public class CustomerFilter { public Func<Customer, string> Selector; public string Filter; }
    [TestMethod()]
    public void DynamicFilterTest()
    {
        var jonSkeet = new Customer() { FirstName = "Jon", LastName = "Skeet" };
        var joelOnSoftware = new Customer() { FirstName = "Joel", LastName = "OnSoftware" };
        var customers = new List<Customer>() { jonSkeet, joelOnSoftware };

        var jonSkeetFilters = new List<CustomerFilter>() { 
            new CustomerFilter() { Selector = c => c.LastName, Filter = "Skeet" },
            new CustomerFilter() { Selector = c => c.FirstName, Filter = "Jon" }};
        var query = customers.AsEnumerable();
        foreach (var filter in jonSkeetFilters)
        {
            query = query.Where(c => filter.Selector.Invoke(c) == filter.Filter);
        }
        var result = query.ToList();
        Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(jonSkeet, result.Single());
    }
```

Then you can easily refactor to use the same patterns for any of your entites :

```
public class WhereClause<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, string> _selector;
    public Func<T, string> Selector { get { return _selector; } }

    private readonly string _value;
    public string Value { get { return _value; } }

    public WhereClause(Func<T, string> selector, string value)
    {
        this._selector = selector;
        this._value = value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Append the where clause to the given query
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="query"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<T> AppendTo(IEnumerable<T> query)
    {
        return query.Where(c => this.Selector.Invoke(c) == this.Value);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Append the wheres clauses to the given query
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="query"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<T> AppendTo(IEnumerable<T> query, IEnumerable<WhereClause<T>> wheres)
    {
        var filteredQuery = query;
        foreach (var where in wheres)
        {
            filteredQuery = where.AppendTo(filteredQuery);
        }
        return filteredQuery;
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class WhereClauseTests
{
    public class Customer { public string FirstName; public string LastName;}

    [TestMethod()]
    public void WhereClauseTest()
    {
        var jonSkeet = new Customer() { FirstName = "Jon", LastName = "Skeet" };
        var joelOnSoftware = new Customer() { FirstName = "Joel", LastName = "OnSoftware" };
        var customers = new List<Customer>() { jonSkeet, joelOnSoftware };

        var jonSkeetWheres = new List<WhereClause<Customer>>() { 
            new WhereClause<Customer>(c => c.LastName, "Skeet"),
            new WhereClause<Customer>(c => c.FirstName,  "Jon" )
        };

        var query = WhereClause<Customer>.AppendTo(customers, jonSkeetWheres);

        var result = query.ToList();
        Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(jonSkeet, result.Single());
    }
}
```

Comment: Haha @ the Jon Skeet Reference.